# If we have rules for parenthesis and signs, why can't we just conclude that $-(+a)(+b)$ is a negative number?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading: Bellman/Beckenbach's Introduction to Inequalities. They present the axioms:

> [image]

And there is a proof about products of negative numbers by positive numbers:

> [image]

If we have the rules for parentheses and minus signs along with the axioms, why can't we do it just like:

$$(+a)(-b)=-(+a)(+b)$$

And conclude that $-(+a)(+b)$ is a negative number?

Comment: That _is_ true, as long as $a, b \in P$: indeed if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $-(+a)(+b)$ is negative. Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @feralin My trouble is that he uses axiom 2, for example. But if you can just use the rules for signs and parenthesis, do you truly need the axiom 2 for that?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I misunderstood your question. Yes, it seems to me that your proof is simpler and also works. I'm also not sure why Bellman and Beckenbach complicate the matter.

Comment: You're using Axiom 2, aren't you, to state that what you write as $-(+a)(+b)$ is negative (since $(+a)(+b)$ is positive, but that's Axiom 2).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I see now that If I turn off axiom 2, $-(+a)(+b)$ is a meaningless string of text and (assuming we have only axiom 1), we couldn't determine if it is positive, negative nor zero. The point was somewhat different of what I was thinking.